# MySQL: How to store/retrieve artist information?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

It's very confusing; it seems like I'll need to have at least one many-to-many relationship.

1. A track might be sung by 2+ artist - how can I store that in the database?
2. While showing that track, I want link to each artist so that when users click the track it opens that artist's profile page.

Can anyone provide me with some assistance in designing a class or classes to accomplish this?

Comment: This smells of homework. Many to many relationship as both answers state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that

```
tblSongs
   SongId
   Title
   YearProduced
   etc.

tblArtist
   ArtistId
   Name
   ProfilePage
   etc..

tblSongArtists
    SongId
    ArtistId
```

Then your queries could look something like

```
SELECT Title, YearProduced, Name, ProfilePage
FROM tblSongs  S
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblSongArtists SA ON SA.SongId = S.SongId
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblArtists A ON A.ArtistId = SA.ArtistId
WHERE Title = 'I got the blues'  -- ....
ORDER BY SongId  -- or Song Title  (*)
```

(*) order by clause is in case the search criteria produces more than one song, and if you wish to keep the artists for a given song in sequence.
Such a query produces multiple rows for a song with several artists, one row per artists, the values of the columns from tblSongs being repeated.

Comment: i m also adding artist_id in my album table... n also in track table ..m i wrong ?

Comment: i think there is no use of artist_id in album table...its getting confusing.

Comment: @sunidhi  On adding (or not adding) artist_id to album table...  That is to be avoided, becasuse I'm assuming it is possible to have _serveral_ artists associated with a given album.  You will then either need a tblAlbumArtists table (similar to tblSongArtists), or to select the list of artists [for a given album] indirectly with some' like that:  tblAlbums -> tblbSongs -> thlSongArtists -> tblArtists  In such a query you would need to use DISTINCT so you only get each artist listed once, even though he/she may be related to several songs of the album.

Comment: plz check my funtion i added in this as answer below

Answer (score 1):

Any many-to-many relationship requires three tables.  For your example:

```
Song<br/> 
Name  SongID

Artist <br/>
Name  ArtistID

ArtistsInSongs <br/>
ArtistID SongID
```

I'll let you figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function find_artist_on($track_id=0) {
    global $database;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . self::$table_name ." s " ;
    $sql .= "LEFT OUTER JOIN trackartist TA ON TA.track_id =s.track_id";
    $sql .= "LEFT OUTER JOIN artist A ON A.artist_id =TA.artist_id";
    $sql .= " WHERE s.artist_id=" .$database->escape_value($track_id);
    $sql .= " ORDER BY artist_id ASC";
    return self::find_by_sql($sql);
    }
```